# Git push warning: Unable to migrate objects to permanent storage

Tags: git, git-push

I have the following problem with git - when I try to push my commits to the origin (which in my case is a network folder) it gives this errors:

> warning: **unable to unlink** './objects/incoming-a16140/6f': Directory not empty
>
> error: **unable to write sha1 filename** ./objects/6f: Directory not empty
>
> warning: **unable to unlink** './objects/incoming-a16140/cf': Directory not empty
>
> error: **unable to write sha1 filename** ./objects/cf: Directory not empty
> To X:strengs_master.git
> ! [remote rejected] bugs/wind_zone_2_Poland -> bugs/wind_zone_2_Poland (**unable to migrate objects to permanent storage**)
> <

It was used to work before, but what is interesting here is that (compared to the similar problems I read) when i try 3 to 5 times usually it manage to push it at the end. But each time I have to make several attempts until successful.

My git version is: git version 2.19.0.windows.1

I have permission to access the folder on the server and also I have access remotely from external IP via ssh where no such a problem exist.

Many thanks for any suggestions that would help!

Comment: Never keep a Git repo on some sort of shared drive.

Comment: What do you mean not to keep it on a shared drive (where it should be kept so the rest of the users has access to it)? It is a network location and it was working like this before.

Comment: You said "which in my case is a network folder". That's a concern.

Comment: I'm I wrong, but git repo should be kept somewhere, right? What is the difference if it is on the server on locally - in both cases there is full access. Could you tell what should be the correct way to do it?

Comment: Network drive usually means something like onedrive, google drive, dropbox, etc. Those will corrupt the repo and maybe cause the sort of issue you're describing.

Comment: OK so in this case by network drive I mean a folder on the local server we have.

Comment: The issue with putting a shared repository on a network share is that git is not designed for concurrent access at that level. **Usually** you use a HTTPS or SSH protocol to access the central git repository with actual git server software running on the server. That software makes sure that no race conditions happen and corrupt your repository. If you use a network share, no such server-side software is involved and you can easily get a corrupted repository. If it worked for a while that just means you got lucky.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to upgrade to Git 2.33.0.2, [the latest Git for Windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

> so in this case by network drive I mean a folder on the local server we have.

Second, check your remote origin network path. It should be like:

```
file:////network/path/to/git-repository'
```

It was problematic in Git 2.11 (2017, [issue 979](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/979)), but your 2.19 version might have a regression.

Comment: We changed the repository location and now we are using ssh keys, so this issue is no longer on the table. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: @Georgi Good call. Still, upgrading Git to its latest version remains a good practice.